# Connecting Android socket client to C socket server

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I want to send some data over an android app to a c server.

I have followed [this](http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/) tutorial to get the basic framework.

I replaced the following code

```
        socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                1024);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead;
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();

        /*
         * notice: inputStream.read() will block if no data return
         */
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            response += byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
        }
```

with my own

```
     System.out.println("Connecting to " + serverName + " on port " + port);
     Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
     System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

     PrintWriter outToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));

     outToServer.println("Hello from " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
     outToServer.flush();

     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
     System.out.println("Server Says : " + in.readLine());
```

I tested my java code and it correctly sends and receives data, but when I try to do the same in android, I would get stuck at

```
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
```

I can see from the Android Monitor it prints

```
I/System.out: Connecting to 100.82.232.126 on port 5001
```

And then it hangs.

Comment: Sounds more like a networking than a coding problem.  Have you tried putting them both on the same wifi and making sure your router allows access to port 5001 on that machine?

Comment: So what does this have to do with C? That the server is written in C? Or Android is written in C?

Comment: I am on the same wifi network. The server is written in C.